# Converting date format from d/m/y time to d/m/y

Tags: r, date, date-formatting

I have data input coming in the form of d/m/y time eg: "3/27/2017 1:20:15 AM" and I want to just have d/m/y to display 3/27/2017.

I have seen different techniques on how to achieve this and have tried 3 different types however I recieve NA as the new output and for the later I get the "Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"
error.

Here is an my example code:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = "3/27/2017 1:20:15 AM")

df$Date <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df$Date), format = "%d/%m/%Y")

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")

df$Date <- format(as.Date(df$Date), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want format = `%m/%d/%Y` instead of `%d/%m/%Y`.

If specialized date formats are still giving you problems with the time after that, you can first use `strsplit()` to break up the character string on spaces, then grab the first item to get just the date.

```
date <- "3/27/2017 1:20:15 AM"
date <- strsplit(date," ")
date <- unlist(date)[1]
date <- as.POSIXct(date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide complete format string in order to identify it as a date-time.
In your case it would be something like this:

```
as.Date("3/27/2017 1:20:15 AM", format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```